# MFC IVideoWindow put_FullScreenMode works incorrectly

Tags: winapi, video, mfc, fullscreen, directshow

So I have next problem:
I have two monitors and do video translation from web camera on one of them(secondary). I do it in full screen mode using 
`put_FullScreenMode()`.

It works fine but when I click any mouse button on area of primary monitor, window with video translation wrap into just window mode. 
How can I save full screen mode working with primary monitor?

At the first, I move my video to the left (on secondary monito from primary) and use full screen mode.

```
    if(monitors.GetCount() > 1)
        gx.pVW->put_Left(primaryRect.right);

        gx.pVW->put_FullScreenMode(OATRUE);
        gx.pVW->put_Visible(OATRUE);
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Much] older applications took advantage of `FullScreenMode` since API supplied a specific "full screen renderer" filter which efficiently took care of full screen presentation. Since then video adapters found their way into stretching of presented video and full screen mode become unnecessary. Windowed mode of video renderer (you are using) was also not a recommended mode compared to windowless any longer.

You would be better off using renderer in windowless mode right in your UI, in your window, form or dialog. Using borderless window hosting video renderer you can easily imitate full screen mode without actually change of display mode. Such window remains normal window and does not need to go back from full screen with another UI activity, e.g. such that happens on another monitor.

VMR filters themselves demonstrate the two ways of going fullscreen in their Filter Config property page:

[image]

Set Fullscreen does it the way you do and suffer from the mentioned issue. The other method does full screen mode using borderless window stretched to the extent of a monitor.

See also related discussion:

- [`IVideoWindow::put_FullScreen` returning only native video size](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/7dbc2adf-dff6-41f1-a9a7-bfece65ed63b/ivideowindowputfullscreen-returning-only-native-video-size?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment)